# Where to focus when taking a portrait of 2 people?

Tags: autofocus, portrait, focus

Could someone please tell me where to focus when taking a portrait picture of a couple who are standing next to each other. Thank You

Comment: Related: [How to calculate camera settings for a family group portrait with a film camera and flash?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/57527)

Comment: Related: [Why focus on the eye closest to the camera instead of the eye in the middle?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/89452)

Comment: The part of your question that asks what settings to use, if it were its own question, would probably be closed as either unclear what you're asking, or too broad. The exposure settings are entirely dependent upon the scene and lighting conditions.

Comment: "Settings" are irrelevant - you just need to know where to focus. As they are next to each-other, focus on a face.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a wide aperture thus having a shallow depth of field it is best to focus on the eyes of the person closest to the camera(even if they are in the same plane, one of them will still be eventually a little closer). This is because viewers usually concentrate on the subject that is in front.

If you use a narrow aperture such as 8 or 9 you should still focus on the closer person but it will not make such a great difference.